# Types compatibility

Tags: typescript, types, compatibility

TypeScript documentation declares:
Private and protected members in a class affect their compatibility ... ... This allows a class to be assignment compatible with its super class, but not with classes from a different inheritance hierarchy which otherwise have the same shape.

The question is: why is this rule not applied to public members?
Look at the example below:

```
class Sugar {
    do() { console.log('Let\s make our life sweeter!') }
}
class Dynamite {
    do() { console.log('Let\s destroy everything!') }
}
let s: Sugar = new Sugar()
let d: Dynamite = new Dynamite()
// ...
// An inaccurate assignment:
s = d
// ...
s.do()
```

Just one inaccurate assignment that TypeScript allowed to do and you have the absolutely unexpected result. Please notice, the classes don't have any common superclass!
Where the logics is: to compare private and protected methods, which can not be called from outside the classes and so can not be called by mistake, and not to pay any attention to public ones which are most error prone?

Thanks for explanations in advance!

Comment: TypeScript is *structurally*, not nominally, typed. Both things have a do method, so the consumer doesn't care which one it gets.

Comment: See [the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) for more information.